JavaScript Form Validation and Submission Issue
Description:
I'm encountering an issue with my JavaScript code for form validation and submission. Here's the breakdown of what I'm trying to achieve and the problems I'm facing:
Goals:

Allow users to add their email and submit the form.
Display a success message with their email after successfully submitting the form.
Implement form validation to show error messages if:

The field is left empty.
The email address is not formatted correctly (should end with "@gmail.com").



Current Issues:

The form validation is not working as expected. Even though I'm typing in an email address ending with "@gmail.com," it only shows the error message without validating.
When clicking on the submit button, it doesn't take me to the page specified in another HTML file within the same project.

Code Snippets:
HTML:
<div id="main">
  <div class="section">
    <!-- Other HTML elements -->
    <p class="Email">Email address</p>
    <input type="email" id="Email" placeholder="email@company.com">
    <div id="error-message"></div>
    <button id="valid" type="button">Subscribe to monthly newsletter</button> 
  </div>
  <div class="illustration-sign-up-desktop">
    <img src="./assets/images/illustration-sign-up-desktop.svg" height="550px" alt="illustration-sign-up-desktop">
  </div>  
</div>

JavaScript:
var Email = document.getElementById('Email');
var error = document.getElementById('error-message');
var validbutton = document.getElementById('valid');
var userEmail;

Email.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    var userEmail = Email.value.toLowerCase();
    var gmailRegex = /^[^@]+gmail\.com$/;
    if (!gmailRegex.test(userEmail)) {
        error.textContent = 'Valid email required';
        error.classList.add('error-message');
    } else {
        error.textContent = '';
        error.classList.remove('error-message');
    }
});

validbutton.addEventListener('click', validateEmail);

function validateEmail () {
    var userEmail = Email.value.toLowerCase();
    var gmailRegex = /^[^@]+gmail\.com$/;
    if (!gmailRegex.test(userEmail)) {
        error.textContent = 'Valid email required';
        error.classList.add('error-message');
    } else {
        // Assuming you want to navigate to 'confirmation.html' upon successful validation
        window.location.href = 'confirmation.html';
    }
}

Additional Notes:

I'm using window.location.href to redirect to the confirmation page upon successful validation.
The email validation logic checks if the email ends with "@gmail.com".
Any assistance in resolving these issues would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!


This regex: /^[^@]+gmail\.com$/ means "anything with no "@" characters and ending with "gmail.com". You're excluding the "@" from your pattern.

There should not be global vars with the same name as local vars, e.g. userEmail. Validation could be performed in a function rather than repeating it for each of user input and form submission, mostly because it's complex even though it's short. Google also has more email addresses than gmail.com, at least in some countries (as of 2023).

Why not just use <input type="email" required>? The browser will do both validations automatically.

You could use the build-in form validation. If there are any required form fields, they all need to be valid before the form will submit.
The validity of the email is based on the pattern attribute on the input element.


document.forms.form01.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.classList.add('invalid');
}, true);

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('input', e => {
  if(e.target.validity.valid){
    e.target.classList.remove('invalid');
  }
});

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.location.href = 'confirmation.html';
});
.error-message {
  visibility: hidden;
}

input.invalid~.error-message {
  visibility: visible;
}
<div id="main">
  <div class="section">
    <!-- Other HTML elements -->
    <form name="form01">
      <p class="Email">Email address</p>
      <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="email@company.com"
        pattern=".*@[gG][mM][aA][iI][lL]\.[cC][oO][mM]" required>
      <div class="error-message">Valid email required</div>
      <button type="submit">Subscribe to monthly newsletter</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>



